# Qt Postgres 'driver not loaded'

Tags: postgresql, qt, driver, qt4.8

I use Windows 10 and Qt version 4.8.6 (msvc).

I try to connect to my postgres database but I always got the error 'driver not loaded'.
I copied libpq.dll to the path of the executable and in the directory plugins, which I copied under the executable path.

This is my code:

```
dbPhilo.setHostName("127.0.0.1"); 
dbPhilo.setPort(5433);
dbPhilo.setDatabaseName("postgres"); 
dbPhilo.setUserName("postgres");
dbPhilo.setPassword("toor");

if(dbPhilo.open())
...
```

In the documentation, this line doesn't work:

```
qmake -- PSQL_INCDIR=C:/psql/include PSQL_LIBDIR=C:/psql/lib/ms
```

It shows me the documentation of qmake.

Is there a way to download the correct dll from a website ?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Did you compile the postgres support plugin for Qt? Related: [https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/sql-driver.html](https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/sql-driver.html)

Comment: the command qmake does not work, it shows me the documentation of qmake instead of compilling

Comment: now, when I run QMAKE, I have an error on clui.dll. I copied this dll in the same folder and added the path to the environment variable PATH but nothing changes, I still got the error...